# How can i make openerp (odoo) to be accessible for portal users through internet?

Tags: hosting, odoo

I know how to configure the portal module on local machine but my question is how could i make it accessible through internet and any employees or customers to have an access?
i have read about hosting on domain name but is there anyone who has an experience?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible by hosting your OpenERP on a server on Internet. There are also hosting solutions for that which are specialized for OpenERP, like [My ERP Engine](https://www.myerpengine.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible to do it.
You just need to find a hosting company.
Example : http://www.arvixe.com/openerp-hosting